# Android : Widget crashing on device reboot

Tags: android, crash, widget

I am working on a widget and I have noticed that the android gives a message that widget has stopped working on rebooting the device. After receiving the next update in 30 mins, it continues to work as normal. How can I debug what is causing the widget to crash on reboot or better still, how can I avoid crash on reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So after a few hours of effort, I managed to find a fix (works for me at least).

In the onReceive, I was performing the following operation:

```
        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        if ("ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICKED".equals(intent.getAction())){
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);            
            int appWidgetIds[] = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Refreshing data. Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            //onUpdate(context, mgr, appWidgetIds);
            mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout));
            mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.stack_view);
            onUpdate(context, mgr, appWidgetIds);
        } else if ("ACTION_BUTTON3_CLICKED".equals(intent.getAction())){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        } else {
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);            
            int appWidgetIds[] = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
            onUpdate(context, mgr, appWidgetIds);
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
```

onReceive and the reboot don't play well together. I put a check that if onReceive is called within a minute of reboot, don't act on it. Putting the following check before anything else is done in onReceive seemed to have addressed the issue.

```
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() < 60000){
            return;
        }
```